# Flex 4.6 Mobile: Play a local video

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, video, flex4.6

I'm developing an application that needs to have a video but without having an internet connection.
I searched for a straight forward solution but I couldn't see a clear one.

Can I embed the video? (I couldn't, it isn't allowed?)

Is it still good to create a SWF with it inside and then embed it? or it lost its quality / performance?

Any other solution?

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: please anyone! at least tell me if it's possible!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can play videos on your application. There are 2 possible ways :

1) Storing videos locally in device storage (SDCard)
2) Embed video to the application package (assets)